# ORDER BY in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a column of a type string that contains values in rows like:

```
1-1
1-5
1-14
1-7
1-3
```

Now if I use the ORDER BY on that column I get the order as:

```
1-1
1-14
1-3
1-5
1-7
```

What would be the proper way to order it as `1-1, 1-3, 1-5,1-7,1-14`

Thank you for your time

Comment: There is no easy way with that data as is,. Can you alter the schema to store the data in another way?

Comment: Is the "1-" the same for all fields, or do you also have "2-", "3-", and "10-"? Are these really date fields (month and day)? Does "1-31" come before or after "2-1"?

Comment: @Mark Cant change the schema unfortunately.  @rajah9 those are not dates, they are some kind of codes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can rename the "1-1" into "1-01"

Comment: Or rename 1-1 to 0001-0001, just to be safe. ;)

Comment: The leading zeros can be removed in formatting in the front end if necessary. Much easier if done this way round :)

Answer (score 10):

Assuming your first character may also vary:

```
order by convert(substr(my_field, 1, locate(my_field, '-') - 1) as int),
         convert(substr(my_field, locate(my_field, '-') + 1) as int)
```

Comment: +1. This is the right answer to the question as posed. That said, a change to the schema might be the better solution.

Answer (score 5):

The proper way would be to store them as integers in different columns.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT *  FROM
(
SELECT '1-1' Id
UNION
SELECT '1-5' Id
UNION
SELECT '1-14' Id
UNION
SELECT '1-7' Id
UNION
SELECT '1-3' Id
) a
ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(Id, '-', '') AS UNSIGNED)
```

Comment: Nice approach, but you will get trouble with 2-1 being smaller than 1-11.  you would have to split, cast both and order by first value, second value

Comment: This would put `11-3` before `1-14`.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a possibility to split the column in 2 separate columns and concat the two together after sorting them individually?

The problem now is that your column is sorting as strings not as integers.

Answer (score 1):

If there's absolutely impossible to make any changes to the structure, I'd say that Carl Manaster's method is best. That would work slow on large data sets though.

You can also try to add a "sort" column (and index it), then each time a new code is added you can calculate it's value e.g.:

1-5  becomes 1000 + 5 = 1005
1-14 becomes 1000 + 14 = 1014

and save it to that sort column. That will work much faster.
You can also write a simple trigger so that this sort value is calculated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like (if the first letter doesn-t metter)

order by CAST(SUBSTRING(field, CHARINDEX(field,'-',0)+1, LEN(field)+1) as int)

Not very pretty though..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT '1-1' Id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT '1-5' Id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT '1-14' Id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT '1-7' Id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT '1-3' Id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT '10-4' Id
        ) a
ORDER BY
        CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(id, '-', -2), '-', 1) AS UNSIGNED),
        CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(id, '-', -1), '-', 1) AS UNSIGNED)
```